# How to make title and date on one line in angular material

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have a title and date , but they are looking now like this:

```
title
date
```

but it has to be: title date.

```
 <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title  >
        <span [innerHTML]="item.title | highlight : searchQuery"></span>
        <span class="spacer"></span>
        <span>
          <a mat-icon-button [routerLink]="['../', dossier.id , 'item', item.id]" i18n-title title="Edit">
            <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
          </a>
        </span>
      </mat-card-title>

      <mat-card-subtitle >
        <span *ngIf="!createdAtEqualsDate(item)">{{item.date | date: 'shortDate'}} <ng-template i18n>created</ng-template></span>
        <span>{{item.createdAt | date: 'short'}}</span>
        <span *ngIf="item.createdAt !== item.lastModifiedAt"><ng-template i18n>modified</ng-template> {{item.lastModifiedAt | date: 'short'}}</span>
      </mat-card-subtitle>
    </mat-card-header>
```

css:

```
mat-card-header{
  justify-content: center;
}
```

So what I mean is that card-title and card-subtitle are on the same line and not under each other

I tried this example https://jsfiddle.net/VanessaRC/Lz9vz6bs/1/. But that doesnt fix it. Because I have a mat-card-header

oke, I have it now like this:

```
 <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title>
        <span [innerHTML]="item.title | highlight: searchQuery"></span>
        <span class="spacer"></span>

      </mat-card-title>

      <div class="title-date">

        <span *ngIf="!createdAtEqualsDate(item)"
          >{{ item.date | date: 'shortDate' }}<ng-template i18n>created</ng-template></span
        >
        <span>{{ item.createdAt | date: 'short' }}</span>
        <span *ngIf="item.createdAt !== item.lastModifiedAt"
          ><ng-template i18n>modified</ng-template> {{ item.lastModifiedAt | date: 'short' }}</span
        >

      </div>

      <span>
        <a mat-icon-button [routerLink]="['../', dossier.id, 'item', item.id]" i18n-title title="Edit">
          <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
        </a>
      </span>
    </mat-card-header>
```

But then the date is on the left side next to the edit icon. But It has to be next to the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your styles, you will need to make a little more adjustments

```
.mat-card-header-text{
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use

```
.mat-card-header-text{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp